# Are there specific legal issues for web developers working on sex dating sites?

Tags: website-design, legal, privacy, privacy-policy

Say I have created many ordinary websites which are not related to any dating/sexual content.

Are the rules and regulations for a developer the same when making a sex-related dating site?

I'm talking about a site where people meet together and get to know each other, with the intent of having a sexual relationship (you know what I mean), also featuring webcam sex, but not explicitly a porno site.

Do such sites have any special legal issues for developers compared with non-sexual/dating sites?

Comment: I would say this probably strays outside of general practice for webmasters and you won't really get a reliable answer here. I hate to say consult a lawyer because it's usually not that easy, but you might have to do that (or at least do some legal reading in your legal jurisdiction).

Comment: Do not quote as legal advice; I'm merely speaking opinion: The developer should not responsible for the website at all if you're doing it for a client, and explicitly make the client aware of any repercussions. As long as you comply with the http://www.coppa.org/ and guarantee that nobody under 18 is using the site, (the owner's responsibility anyway), you should be fine.

Comment: @ionFish - I totally agree - to the point when I do sites I always put on my own disclaimer which says the site content or the server has nothing to do with me etc. +1

Comment: Although I would say, if it's a site where people can upload images then this may be an issue - there MAY be issues between a 'meeting up' site where all actual content is 'tame' compared to a picture of 'what you'll get when we meet!'

Answer (score 1):

You should have a general disclaimer stating you can not be held responsible for the actual site/server. You build the site to specifications. If the person paying you doesn't specify certain items, you're really not on the hook. You can recommend certain things, but as a developer, no. As long as you're not in a continued relationship with them. For the initial development, I wouldn't say there is anything you need to be worried about except what the customer wants.

Granted, your mileage may vary based on your exact location and you may have certain responsibilities as the developer based on law or legal precedence.

Comment: Just for the record of such question. What if i am the owner of the site and i am the developer of the site too?

Comment: Then you would need to consult the different laws for the area you're in. Such as record keeping for nude models, access control for under 18, etc. as you would then be responsible.

Comment: @YumYumYum: Edit your question. Developers and site owners have very different responsibilities. You may be better asking on Law.SE.